# In Scala, how can I turn a bunch of CSV files into an array of arrays

Tags: scala

I'm looking to transform all the files into `Array[Array[String]]`.  The first dimension should be the row number.  The second dimension should be the column number.  So far I have

```
  for (file <- allFiles) {

    val split = for (line <- Source.fromFile(...) yield line.split(",")

  } yield split
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  As a concrete example if I had

file1.csv

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

file2.csv

```
1,2,3
```

I would want as output

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By doing this:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(...)) ...
```

You are iterating over each character from the file, not each line.

You probably meant:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(...).getLines) ...
```

By the way, you can combine your two `for` comprehensions into one:

```
scala> val allFiles = Array("data1.csv", "data2.csv")
allFiles: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(data1.csv, data2.csv)

scala> for {
     |   filename <- allFiles
     |   line <- io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
     | } yield line.split(",")
res3: Array[Array[java.lang.String]] = Array(Array(a, b, c), Array(d, e, f), Array(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ben's answer is good (I upvoted it), but it's possible to go a bit further with for-comprehensions - and make the code more readable and self-documenting in the process.

The trick is to use `=` in the comprehension, as well as `<-`. A nice feature that's not seen nearly often enough in the wild:

```
val allFiles = Array("data1.csv", "data2.csv")
val parsedLines = for {
  filename <- allFiles
  file = io.Source fromFile filename
  line <- file.getLines
  entries = line split ","
} yield entries
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need this for *production* (that is, you have to handle real CSV files, which can be more complex than the name would suggest, what with quotation marks and all), use Apache's [Common CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) library.  It's in Java but hey, if we didn't need Java compatibility, we'd all be using Haskell, amirite?

Answer (score 1):

Or use a one-liner:

```
val aa = List ("abc.csv", "123.csv").map (io.Source.fromFile (_).getLines .map (_.split (","))).flatten.toArray
aa: Array[Array[java.lang.String]] = Array(Array(a, b, c), Array(d, e, f), Array(1, 2, 3))
```

Not that I would recommend one-liners. Just as an alternative.