# Load CSV file to a 2-D array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, csv

I am trying to load a csv file into a 2-D array, and my code is as follows:

```
var data: Array[Array[AnyRef]] = _
data = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.map(_.split(",")).flatten.toArray
```

But it doesn't work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130966/in-scala-how-can-i-turn-a-bunch-of-csv-files-into-an-array-of-arrays)
provides couple of solutions, but none works for me for some reason.

Does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: What does it mean - "it doesn't work" ? Please, add your expected result and your actual result.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to compile, the syntax is wrong. I deleted flatten method, but still no compilation.

Comment: What is the error? What is the format of the data you're trying to parse? Did you include  `import scala.io.Source` ? What is the type of data into your csv? why put `AnyRef` if it might be strings or int? And also, why flatten it?